# Accessing Multiple COS instance under the same IBM account

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

I am trying to access multiple COS instances which are there under the same IBM account. I see that each COS instance is having different accesskey,secret-key. The property in hive.xml(fs.s3a.access.key,fs.s3a.secret.key) can accept only one value at a time for one instance. If i provide multiple accesskeys,secretkeys like access.key1 its not working as hive doesnot understand which instance this key belongs to. Any suggestion or alternative to fix this issue. IBM cloud storage has an additional layer of COS instance--> buckets when compared to the amazon s3 where its just buckets. For someone who is not familar with IBM cloud this question can be thought of as, Will it be possible to refer two different s3 accounts in the same hive config. Because these two different s3 accounts will have different pair of keys.
NOTE:notice *multiple cos instances* is IBM cloud specific term. in the context of aws, all s3 buckets are identified by buckets.

1.Multiple hive instances for multiple cos instances. This thing mite work but i feel we might end up having n number of instances.
2. Tried to add more properties in core-site.xml like (fs.s3a.secret.key,fs.s3a.secret1.key) this didnt work for the second instance.

````
       <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
       <value>xxxxxxxx</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
     <value>xxxxxxxx</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
     <value>xxxxxxxx</value>
   </property>```
````

Comment: What do you do with the data? Some connectors allow per-bucket authentication and hence access to multiple accounts, not just IBM.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your using an older, IaaS COS setup.

Ideally, you'd migrate to the newer IAM-enabled service, where you can easily use one set of credentials for whichever service instance or bucket you want to grant access to.  This is because IAM will assign credentials to an identity instead of to the Service Instance (or Storage Account, the terminology can be inconsistent).

Credentials can be associated with a "Service ID", and that "Service ID" (basically a non-human user) can be the subject of access policies that grant roles on each of the instances that you want the ID to access.

Typically, the primary reason to have multiple instances is to provide for more granularity in billing - there's no practical restriction on the amount of data in an instance or the number of objects in a bucket (although the number of buckets in an instance should be limited to the hundreds in most cases).

Also, as a fun fact, "instance" is a bit of a misnomer.  COS is a true multitenant system - the entire public cloud is a single instance of COS (both IaaS and IAM-enabled are actually different windows into the same system).  So when you provision a new "instance", you are actually getting access to create new buckets within a billable entity in the existing system, but nothing new is actually being spun up for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an unusual situation; distcp across accounts is common even in AWS S3.

Hadoop 2.8+ supports "per-bucket configuration", where you can define the secrets (and any other option) for individual buckets: [per bucket configuration](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current3/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/#Configuring_different_S3_buckets_with_Per-Bucket_Configuration)

This should be sufficient.